# Looking for a non-$\sigma$-finite measure for a counter example

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is just the context:

It can be shown, for a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on a measurable spaces $X$, the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $[0,+\infty)$, and a measurable function $f:X\to [0,+\infty)$, that:
$$\int_X f(x) d\mu= \mu\times\lambda\ (E)$$
Where $E=\{(x,t): t<f(x)\}$ is the 'area under the graph' of $f$, and $E$ is measurable.

This is the question :

$$\int_X f(x) d\mu= \int_0^{+\infty} \mu(\{x: f(x)>t\})\ dt$$

What is a possible counter example for that equality? We want it to fail for some non-$\sigma$-finite measure.

Comment: It is not needed for $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite, but for the carrier of $f$, $\{|f|>0\}$,  to be $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: As for examples where the cake-layer type of integration fails, consider any uncountable set $\Omega$ equipped with the co-countable $\sigma$-algebra  $\mathcal{C}$ ($A$ is measurable if either $A$ or $\Omega\setminus A$ is countable). The counting measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega,\mathacr{C})$ will be a good place to consider.

Comment: You mean by the carrier the support of $f$? We have no topology on $X$, so how to define $X$ being sigma-finite?

Comment: By the counting measure you mean take the measure to be $0$ for countable sets and $+\infty$ for uncoutable ones? Is this any different from considering the real line with the counting measure? For which I sort of proved it will not work.

Comment: The carrier is not the support (the support is the closure of the carrier assuming the underlaying space is a topological space), the carrier is what I said: $\{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega)\neq0\}=\{\omega\in\Omega: |f(\omega)|>0\}$. Fubini-tonelli's theorem (which is what one used to use the cake-layer type of integral when integration is defined  a la Lebesgue or a la Daniell) works for functions with $\sigma$-finite carriers.

Comment: I just recalled that there is another approach to integration (See Analysis, Lieb and Loss, AMS) that defines integration starting from $\int^\infty_0\mu(f>t)\,dt$ for $f\geq0$ as a definition. So the identity always holds for all meaurable nonnegative function (the integral in the expression in my comment can be taken as a Riemann improper integral)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited and rewritten:** I'm pretty confident that $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu$ is not needed to prove the second equality!

> **Claim:** Let $\mu$ be a measure on a measurable space $X$. ($\mu$ may or may not be $\sigma$-finite.) Let $f: X \to [0, \infty)$ be a positive $\mu$-measurable function.
> Then:
>
> - For all $t \in [0, \infty)$, the set $\{ x \in X : f(x) > t \}$ is $\mu$-measurable.
> - The function $t \mapsto \mu ( \{ x \in X : f(x) > t \} )$ is Lebesgue-measurable.
> - $\int_X f(x) d\mu(x) = \int_0^\infty \mu ( \{ x \in X : f(x) > t \} ) dt$.

**Proof:** The first bullet point holds by the definition of what it means for $f$ to be measurable.

The second bullet point holds because the function $t \mapsto \mu\{ x \in X : f(x) > t \}$ is monotonically decreasing, and all monotonic functions are Lebesgue measurable.

For the third bullet point, observe that there exists a sequence of positive simple ($\mu$-measurable) functions $s_n$ such that $ s_n(x)\nearrow f(x)$ as $ n\to \infty$ for all $x\in X$. It's clear that the equality that we want to prove is true when $f$ is replaced with any of the $s_n$'s. All that then remains is to apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem on both sides of the equality.

Comment: But the second equality that I ask about need no product measure, I am not sure if the second integral is well defined, that is, $t\mapsto \mu(\{x: f(x)>t\})$ is measurable. But here assume it is well defined, and find a counter example, or just find a counter example where it is not well defined.

Comment: I am just noticing your edit after I commented, let me check that.

Comment: @KennyWong: There is an approach to integration that takes $\int^\infty_0\mu(f>t)\,dt$ (taken as an improper Riemann integral) as the definition of integral for any nonnegative measurable function. See Lieb and Loss Analysis, AMS. That yields the same type of integral that Lebegue-Charathepdoty or Daniell's methods give.

Comment: @Mittens Ah, so this is a standard approach covered in a textbook! I didn't know that. I might have to think longer to figure out why $t \mapsto \mu(f > t)$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, T]$ for any $T > 0$...

Comment: @KennyWong: though not widely used, it is indeed one way to construct the Lebesgue integral based on measure theory and Riemann integration. It is also rather economical in deriving the essential theorems of Lebesgue integration (monotone convergence and dominated convergence), at least that how it seems by taking a look at Lieb and Loss's book.

Comment: Then I should read Lieb and Loss one day! It feels so weird that I never learnt that this definition is equivalent to the Lebesgue one. (I assumed all my life that you had to go via Fubini, and rely on $\sigma$-finiteness.)